# Flask Jinja2 Page Freezes after sometime

Tags: ajax, flask, jinja2, mod-wsgi, d3plus

I've deployed a simple **Flask Application on Apache2 in Ubuntu 16.04 x64(Alibaba Cloud) with mod_wsgi.** I'm using mysql as my database server on the same ubuntu server instance. The python version is **3.5**.

In the backend of the application I'm processing data from some database queries from some relatively large database tables.

In frontend page, I'm visualizing the data I'm expecting to get from the backend by **D3PLUS** JS library. And, in a single page, I'm showing 4 charts/graphs in 4 html divs and two other divs to show text data. All of the **requests** for the data is currently handled by **ajax post**.

I've ensured CSRF protection for ajax request by

```
    var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

    $.ajaxSetup({
               beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
        }
    }
});
```

The post request requires around 20-25 seconds to get response normally from the backend. Here is the example of the post request:

```
  $('#company_button').on('click', function(event) {
  var company_name = ($('#company_select').select2('data'))[0].text;
  if (company_name==null){
    alert('Enter a name please!');
  }
  else{
      handle_all(company_name);
  }

  event.preventDefault();
  });

function handle_all(company_name){
    show_loader();
    //baike_getter(event,company_name);
    //recommend_getter(company_name);

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data : JSON.stringify({company_name : company_name}),
        dataType: "json",
        url: flask_util.url_for('_company_info_all'),
        success: function (data) {
                                JSON.parse(data[0].recommendation);

                                remove_loader();
                                update_company(data[0].company_general[0]);
                                all_graphs(data[0].country,data[0].product,data[0].haiguan,data[0].shipping);
                                recommend_getter2(company_name);
                                baike_getter2(event,company_name);
                            }
    });
```

}

The size of the **JSON** data got as response is around 5-10 KB and it includes Chinese text(Unicode).

**The problem** is that after two-three times of sending the batch(Actually only one request which handles processing everything in backend) of **post request** to backend, when data comes as response, the **page freezes** forever. 
Any help will be encouraged. Thanks in advance !

**Edit/Update:** The charts/graphs I'm generating in this page are **tree_map,pie,2 bar charts**. All are with `.format({"locale":"zh_CN"})`. Version used [D3Plus V1](http://d3plus.org/js/d3.js)

Comment: Have you worked out whether the responses actually come back from mod_wsgi? That is whether it is getting stuck in mod_wsgi rather than being a JS or communications issue? There are recipes in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/debugging-techniques.html#tracking-request-and-response for tracking request and response in mod_wsgi to debug what it is doing.

Comment: Extremely sorry for late reply. I'm trying to add middleware from my rookie understanding. By the way, I would like to tell you, I tried to run the same application on my local computer which have the same issue. From the python console there is no error. Even I print something just before sending the final response data which I get easily. 
But if I inspect that request from browser, it just says pending(and freezes). FYI, I get the response and generate the graphs successfully for first two/three times of ajax post. @Graham Dumpleton

Comment: Hi, I set some print statements in some backend (view functions) of the flask app. On var/log/apache2/error.log, I got some 'wsgi.error' labeled error message which are actually the print statements I used earlier. The first error message is just the url parameter i.e. xx.xx.xx.xx/companies/{parameter}. Here is the example https://pastebin.com/Vw612wbB .  
Still dumbfounded in this situation. TIA. @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: You are print out some non ascii strings. Apache logging will escape it.

Comment: Actually even I don't print the non ascii string, the others still appears as wsgi.error. FYI, I checked from the Chrome Postman, every time response data comes successfully. Page freezes after response while generating those few charts. @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: There is nothing actually wrong with stuff appearing flagged as ``wsgi.error``. Anything printed by your Python code to ``stdout`` or ``stderr`` will be logged and will be flagged that way. It is something that can't be changed and how Apache logging works. It doesn't mean there is an actual error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your wise explanation. So, I can come to a point that the freezing/hang issue is all about the moment when generating the graphs/ charts from D3plus not anything about the apache2 or modwsgi. @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: It doesn't rule out there is an issue with your code, with it potentially locking up or not responding quickly. This is why trying to track when requests stop/start can be useful. At the minimum, watch the Apache access log and see if you see all the requests you expect to be logged in there. If they are all logged, it would indicate Apache is sending a response and so issue may be front end code.

Comment: Users were browsing that page for last two days and I've also checked the apache access log where every request is with code 200. @GrahamDumpleton